# Changing font size in one section in the TexShop editor

Tags: fontsize, texshop

I'm running TexShop 4.2 on OSX 10.12.
I'm creating a large table and have issues with the table rows occupying multiple lines in the editor window, which is rather confusing and uncomfortable.
I can reduce the font size of the editor through the Preferences > Source > Document Font menu, but it affects the entire document and becomes difficult to read.
Is there be a way to reduce the font size just for a selected text (in this case the table section) so that I can fit each row with all its corresponding columns in one line (i.e. to have one row per line)?

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think there's any way to do this. Are there editors that can do that?